# How to get the correct value when a masked input is edited(custom masking)

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking, data-masking

I have two inputs(masked and unmasked) and a toggle button that serves as a show/hide button. It works similarly as password masking except that it only masks certain characters in a string. Whatever I input in the `unmasked` text box, `createMask` function is called and the result is shown in the `masked` text box.

The problem is, when the masked text box is shown and I edit the value, it should update the value in the unmasked text box.

For example, `12345678` -> `1XXXX678`

Then I will edit `1XXXX678` to `1XXXX619`

When I click the button to unmask, it should show `12345619`

For better understanding, here's the full code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/759ncLhr/)

Comment: What is supposed to happen when a value that was masked is changed? I know this isn't too helpful, but this seems like a poor UX. Perhaps you could just unmask the field when it's focused, to keep things simple?

Comment: @Matthematics Indeed it is a poor UX. It makes it complicated. Actually, I thought of what you have suggested. But it defeats the purpose of the button. And the user wants the button haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the real value in a data attribute of the input element, that way you have a single source of truth.

While you are toggling you can get that real value and display masked/unmasked.

Also you need to have a state that is is masked/unmasked so when you are updating values you know that unmasked values can directly substitute to value and masked value will be just first letter and rest letters you have to pick the masked area from last known value

Now when in masked state user changes any of the `X` values I have given a function if it is 'XXXX' it will take the old value if anything else it tries to update the value. I have kept the position of the cursor where the user is at. If you want to get creative you can work on a logic here.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#SSN').on('input', function(e) {
    const this$ = $(this);
    const val = $(this).val();

    if (this$.data('unmask')) {
      this$.data('val', val);
    } else {
      const oldParams = getMask(this$.data('val'), false);
      const newParams = getMask(val, false);
      const newMaskArea = getUpdatedMaskArea(e.target.selectionStart, oldParams.maskArea, newParams.maskArea);
      const newValue = newParams.first + newMaskArea + newParams.rest;
      this$.data('val', newValue);
    }
  }).on('blur', function() {
    const this$ = $(this);
    this$.val(getMask(this$.data('val'), !this$.data('unmask')).value);
  }).data('val', $(this).val())

  $('#toggle').on('click', toggle).trigger('click');
});

function toggle() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash');
  $('#SSN').data('unmask', !$(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-eye-slash')).trigger('blur');
}

function getUpdatedMaskArea(position, oldMask, newMask){
  if(position>=2 && position<=5){
    if(newMask.indexOf('X')===-1){
      return newMask;// user input new value
    } else if(newMask.length === oldMask.length){
      return newMask.replace(/X/g, (v,i)=>oldMask.charAt(i));//user updates 'X'
    } else {
      //when there are less than desired X ? I am not sure how to handle this
    }
  }
  return oldMask;
}

function getMask(val, mask) {
  const first = val.substring(0, 1);
  const maskArea = val.substring(1, 5);
  const rest = val.substring(5, val.length);
  const value = first + (mask ? maskArea.replace(/./g, 'X') : maskArea) + rest;
  return {first, maskArea, rest, value};
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <input id="SSN" maxlength="8">
  <button id="toggle" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: How will I retrieve the original value if I save while the masked value is currently shown? I'm using asp controls by the way

Comment: you can call `$('#SSN').data('val')` will give you the original value

Comment: I noticed on blur that it cuts the string to four characters only. For example input is `12345678` then it will become `1XXX` only